# IF..THEN.. format OUTPUT in SQL-Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, substring, extract

I think I need an If--Then clause to accomplish the below output. I saw previous answers for this question and I cannot (I do not know how) apply it to my case.
I have a column that contains the following text:

```
<p>In 12/12 Maria gave away $14,000,000 of her money to charity</p>    <p>The 10/12 amount was received with enthusiasm.</p>
```

The idea is that I can have multiple paragraphs in the field. What is of interest is only the date from the paragraph that contains the word 'amount' so the expected formatted value of the column should be:

```
10/12
```

The paragraph with the word amount can be randomly positioned between the field contents (in this example it is the second but it can vary);

I apologize in advance for not being able to extract my desired output from the other topics. I am new to this and I worked my way with REPLACE and or CHARINDEX but I did not manage to solve this one. If there is a simpler way to extract that, I would appreciate a hand with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Will it always be "mm/yy amount" or will you have things like "amount in mm/yy"?

Comment: always the same format of the amount: mm/yy

Comment: what I mean is, does the word 'amount' always come just _after_ the date?

Comment: sorry @codeulike , yet, that would be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it always follows the pattern '... mm/yy amount ...' then:

```
Select substring(YourColumn, Charindex('amount', YourColumn)-6,5)
from YourTable
```

This will then give you a string of the form '10/12'. There isn't really any way to turn that into a date unless you have a year as well.

edit from comments: now you're talking. You'll need something like:

```
Select case 
    when Charindex(' amount', YourColumn) > 0 
    then substring(YourColumn, Charindex(' amount', YourColumn)-5,5)
    when Charindex('&nbsp;amount', YourColumn) > 0 
    then substring(YourColumn, Charindex('&nbsp;amount', YourColumn)-5,5)
    else null end as ExtractedInfo
from YourTable
```

Comment: It works perfectly for most of them.

Unfortunately, I do not have writing access to the table and I see it does not work when the column contains

    `<p>The 02/07&nbsp;amount.</p>`

Is there a workaround to catch both cases?

Comment: Hello again, @codeulike!
Thank you for the example of using when then else. Really useful.

Robert,